# undefined reference to `memcpy' error caused by ld

Tags: c, makefile, ld, memcpy

I was developing an embedded project an was struggling to compile it because of this error: 
`mipsel-linux-gnu-ld: main.o: in function 'fooBar':main.c:(.text+0x3ec): undefined reference to 'memcpy'`


This error is caused by every operation similar to this, in which I assign the value of a pointer to a non-pointer type variable.

```
int a = 0;
int *ap = &a;
int c = *ap; //this causes the error
```

Here's another example:

```
state_t *exceptionState = (unsigned int) 0x0FFFF000;
currentProcess->cpu_state = *exceptionState; //this causes the error
```

I have already included the flag `-nostdlib` in the makefile... 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I have already included the flag -nostdlib in the makefile...
```

Take that flag out. It blocks linkage to standard library calls.  The compiler might actually generate references to the memcpy function, even if your code doesn't explicitly call it.

If you absolutely need `-nostdlib`, I suppose you could define your own version of `memcpy` - if that's the only function the linker is complaining about.  It won't be as optimized, but it would work. add the following code to the bottom of one of your source files:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ((char*)dest)[i] = ((char*)src)[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately, I need to use the -nostdlib flag since my professor asked me to use it, and because my program needs to run in an embedded system that cant use the std libraries... and the type size_t is only included in the stdlib (or am I missing something?)

Comment: Turns out a size_t is just an unsigned int and now the code works, thank you for your very helpful answer!

Comment: `size_t` is not `unsigned int`.  It's `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` depending on the type of CPU you have.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have included `-nostdlib` is what's causing your problem.

If you copy a structure the compiler may call the standard C runtime function `memcpy()` to do it.  If you link with `-nostdlib` then you're telling the linker to not include the standard C runtime library.

If you have to use `-nostdlib` then you'll have to provide your own implementation of `memcpy()`.