# C Standard lib functions having undefined reference when programming microcontroller

Tags: c, gcc, std, riscv

I'm trying to write a firmware for a RISCV processor that is supposed to feed some data to a digital circuit. I wanted to get that data from a file instead of generating it in the c firmware. But when I tried to start the simulations all the stdlib functions, such as, fopen(), fgets(), fclose() and memcpy() will have undefined reference. I've checked the makefiles and I saw this:

```
%.elf: %.c $(LINKER_SCRIPT) $(SOURCE_FILES)
    ${GCC_PATH}/${GCC_PREFIX}-gcc -g \
    -I$(FIRMWARE_PATH) \
    -I$(VERILOG_PATH)/dv/generated \
    -I$(VERILOG_PATH)/dv/ \
    -I$(VERILOG_PATH)/common \
      $(CPUFLAGS) \
    -Wl,-Bstatic,-T,$(LINKER_SCRIPT),--strip-debug \
    -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o $@ $(SOURCE_FILES) $<
```

So the -nostdlib option is added. My question is should I define all the std functions I need to get the program working as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66809749/10566333) or is there any other way. Also removing the option from the makefile will causes some errors.

I'm using gcc 9.4.1. and riscv-gnu-toolchain-rv32i. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: `-nostdlib`means no standard library. Where do you expect e.g. the definition of `fopen` to come from?

Comment: @n.m. are there any implementations of the functions that didn't use stdlib I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Implementations of these functions would *be* the stdlib (at least partially).

Comment: Thanks, then I have no choice than to generate the data in the same program.

Answer (score 0):

How I remember newlib is needed for a program to microcontroller compiling,
because standard functions are called from it, but I don't tell from whence
newlib can be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain more? Its a bit hard for me to understand